# Android Xamarin.Forms app crashes upon opening

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application (android). Everything used to be fine until the last build that I downloaded from the App Center. When I try to open the app, it appears for a moment, and then disappears. I see it is sitting on the background:

[image]

But when I press it, it immediately disappears again. I tried to get the log messages, and this is what I found

07-18 08:27:01.467  Samsung SM-G973U    Debug   1161    ActivityTaskManager android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:605)
at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:2686)
at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:136)
at com.android.server.wm.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
at com.android.server.wm.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:69)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroyImmediately(ActivityRecord.java:3478)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroyIfPossible(ActivityRecord.java:3390)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.processStoppingAndFinishingActivities(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2347)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.activityIdleInternal(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1666)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor$ActivityStackSupervisorHandler.activityIdleFromMessage(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2948)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor$ActivityStackSupervisorHandler.handleMessageInner(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2981)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor$ActivityStackSupervisorHandler.handleMessage(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2922)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)

I am not sure if this is the cause of my problem though. It works without problem on my Visual Studio emulator, and also when I debug on Visual Studio with the real device.

Comment: What changed between this build and the last working build?  Have you tried adding your own logging or crash reporting?

Comment: @Jason For example, I updated Xamarin.Forms NuGet package. And some others... I also replaced TargetFrameworkVersion from 10.0 to 12.0. Changed EmbedAssembliesIntoApk from false to true. I did not try to add my own logging, as I am not sure where it should go and what to check for. And why does it work when I debug on the same device?!

Comment: App enter.ms has crash reporting tools, have you tried them?  Or rolling back to your previous version and applying the changes one at a time until you discover the culprit?

Comment: @Jason I added some more of my changes to my previous comment. I used the Device Log tool on VS. Can't find enter.ms. Could you please give me some reference? Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/

Comment: @Jason That speaks about App Center diagnostics. What about enter.ms? And the Diagnostics shows problems not in real-time, the newest is yesterday...

Comment: Yes, AppCenter.  There is a typo in my earlier comment.  Do you have them enabled in your app?  And I never claimed they were real time.

Comment: @Jason Then I will have to wait until tomorrow...

Comment: Read the AppCenter docs.  It discusses how apps submit crash reports and how they are processed.  It’s not real-time but it’s not necessarily next day either

Comment: While waiting for crash reports, I would:  1) delete app. 2) Reboot phone. To see if it works from a "clean" state.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Unfortunately, this did not help :(

Comment: What's the android version on the test device?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Samsung SM-G973U (Android 11.0 - API 30). BTW, when I deploy on the device from Visual Studio rather than from App Center.

Comment: Also, it is not just this phone. My colleague tested it on a newer phone with the same result.

Comment: Can you debug it and find which line cause this error? In addition, did you try to get back the previous version step by step?